# Office 365 Sharepoint 2013 web part solution type

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I am seeing mixed information about the type of web parts which can be deployed in an Office 365 Sharepoint 2013 environment. Can these solutions be farm solutions, or does office 365 ONLY support sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

For Office 365 you can use just a SandedBox, but its very recommanded to use the Apps instead the SandedBox WebPart.

A tutorial : [Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/07/27/building-apps-for-sharepoint-and-office-365/)

Comment: Do the Apps support communicatin to other applications? Or communication to sharepoint/other apps?